# My UITableView do not scroll

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uikit

I cannot get my UITableView to load data as i am scrolling. I do have subview in the cell (two lines). It display the first screen correctly but when i scroll only the lines that is on the first screen displays, nothing to scroll.

I have two arrays `cellArray1` (main line) and `cellArray2` (second line) that I load data from.

I would very much appreciate help to solve this, possible, simple problem.

Here is what i think is relevant code for this question:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) getCellContentView:(NSString *)cellIdentifier
{   
    CGRect CellFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 60);
    CGRect Label1Frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 290, 25);
    CGRect Label2Frame = CGRectMake(30, 33, 270, 25);
    UILabel *lblTemp;

    UITableViewCell *cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CellFrame reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];

    //Initialize Label with tag 1.
    lblTemp = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:Label1Frame];
    lblTemp.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    [lblTemp setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"American Typewriter" size:16]];
    lblTemp.tag = 1;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lblTemp];
    [lblTemp release];

    //Initialize Label with tag 2.
    lblTemp = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:Label2Frame];
    lblTemp.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    lblTemp.tag = 2;
    [lblTemp setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"American Typewriter" size:13]];
    lblTemp.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lblTemp];
    [lblTemp release];

    return cell;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) cell = [self getCellContentView:CellIdentifier];

    UILabel *lblTemp1 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    UILabel *lblTemp2 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];

    lblTemp1.text = [cellArray1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    lblTemp2.text = [cellArray2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Only obvious thing I would change is to use:


    initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:

instead of initWithFrame, since this is dep. in ios3.0.

Do you see two orange boxes but text in first box only?  or do you not even see both labels?  also, default cell height is 44 pixels, so your second view may be out of bounds to show.  Make sure you are returning 60pixel as height for cells, with tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: Thanks, but it will still not scroll.

Comment: what do u mean by "not scroll"?  I thought text is not showing up..  also, do u see two boxes or no?

Comment: I just found the problem, i had hard coded a parameter that dictated how many items that was loaded in the array during test. I do apologize that i took your time.

Comment: no problem!  late night coding sessions can do that :D

Comment: If you found the answer please post it as an answer and accept it so it this question does not showed up as unanswered.

Comment: @PeterK ^ What that guy (Nick) said. It doesn't hurt to accept your own answer, and seeing as the problem has been solved, leaving the question alone with 0 answers is misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this problem was that I had hard coded a parameter that dictate how many items that was loaded during my testing.

I just found the problem, i had hard coded a parameter that dictated how many items that was

Answer (score 0):

[image: Select Your View Controller's Xib file than select tableView From View and Enable Scrolling.]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are adding to the correct view if you are creating programatically and adding as subview to main view.